# Read config data from E071K

Tags: abap, documentation-generation, transport, sap-basis

I am entertaining a 'config documenter' feature, which will document a given request by finding tasks in E070 and then the keys in E071K.

E071K only has the table and the key ( the key consists of concatenated keyfields ).
Does anybody know of FM or class to read the tables entry linked to the key found in E071K ?

This would help me tremendously.

Cheers,
T.

Answer (score 0):

...you do realize that the key can be a singular *, meaning that the entire table will be read and in some cases this will probably blow your documenter apart? ;-)

You'll also know that, when an entry ending in a * is transported, the entries in the target system corresponding to the partial key are removed before the import, so you won't be able to document the real changes without examining both the source and the target. I'm just reiterating this for the sake of other poor souls who will try this out.

Other than that, there are a few function modules that can read the contents of the tables involved under certain conditions - namely `SRTT_TABLE_GET_BY_KEYLIST` - but be aware that you'll have to deal with all kinds of table oddities - non-char fields, cluster tables, the whole works - for yourself.

Comment: I was not aware of this, I am documenting initial development, so I dont need to take the target into account. I found/tried SRTT_TABE_GET_BY_KEYLIST and to your point it is not straight forward, so I was hoping someone has done this before and could share a solution. Thanks for checking this out.